# ERROR !! Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe. You need to recompile PHP

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I want to change MPM mode from prefork to worker but on restarting Apache Error ocuur that PHP module is not compiled to be thread safe and secondly i can't understand this.

Comment: Don't know in detail, but looks like you have a non thread safe version of PHP installed in your system, while the mpm module will be looking for creating threads: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html

Comment: Thanks @AshishRanjan I installed PHP-FPM but still when change mode from prefork to worker error occur!!

Answer (score 2):

Check if the statement `LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so` isn't commented and the statement `LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so` is commented in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` (in manjaro).