# Running PHP in Docker Container httpd:latest

Tags: docker, apache, apache2, httpd.conf, docker-desktop

So I’m learning/experimenting with Docker - and I’m running the Apache Container from Docker Hub - Specifically I’m running the latest tag. Here is the command that I used:

```
docker run --name apacheServer -p 80:80 -v $(PWD)/Apache/htdocs:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs httpd:latest
```

Everything is working fine, if I go to http://localhost/ I can see the index.html file in the specified directory. However I’m now trying to add PHP to it and can’t get it to work. This is what I have tried so far.  from the Container’s Interactive Shell I ran the following commands.

```
apt update

apt upgrade -y

apt install php8.2

apt install php libapache2-mod-php -y
```

After doing this. I checked if PHP was installed by running  php -v  Indeed I got the correct version.

```
PHP 8.2.7 (cli) (built: Jun  9 2023 19:37:27) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.7, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

After restarting apache with `apachectl restart` I ran the following command:

```
a2enmod php8.2
```

And I got the following message `“Module php8.2 already enabled”`  However I then tried doing:

```
apachectl -M
```

but the PHP module is not listed in the list. this is the list I got:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
```

So here is where I’m lost. Not sure what to do next. Because If I do

`ls /etc/apache2/mods-available` I can see `php8.2.conf` and `php8.2.load` list but not in `ls /usr/local/apache2/modules/` neither is `libphp8.2.so`

As a last try I ran the following command;

`find /usr/lib/ -name libphp*.so` and got back `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.2.so`

I tried to manually add that file on the /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf file by adding

```
LoadModule php_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.2.so
```

But then I got the following error message when restarting apache: `Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP. AH00013: Pre-configuration failed`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok So I was able to figure it out.

To fix the error `Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP. AH00013: Pre-configuration failed` that I was getting, after adding `LoadModule php_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp8.2.so` to the configuration file I had to comment out `LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so` and uncomment `LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so`.

(Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62041173/4585097).

I also had to add `Include /etc/apache2/mods-available/php8.2.conf` and that did the trick.